# I want to add employee names according to their Id ( EnNo )

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have employees Id (EnNo) in my csv file but I also want to add their names according to there ID .

This is my **output image** of my dataframe but here , I also want to add there names according to their ID(EnNo)

[image]

Please help.. I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude first column by selecting with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and `sum` per rows:

```
df['Attended'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1)
```

Or remove column `EnNo` by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) before `sum`:

```
df['Attended'] = df.drop('EnNo', axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: But sir I want to keep both Employee Id & their name together.. So please tell me how to do this @jezrael